# In Vue2.7, v-slot is not available, how to solve the problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-slot

When I run the following code, I get the following results (Google Chrome running screenshot).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>17-Learning of Scoped Slots and Named Slots</title>
    <style>
      .h1Class{
        color:red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div_new">
      <h1 class="h1Class">first set</h1>
      <cpn></cpn>
      <h1 class="h1Class">second set</h1>
      <cpn>
        <!-- first method -->
        <template  slot="slotName" slot-scope="planallScope">
        <!-- second method after Vue2.6 -->
        <!-- <template v-slot:slotName="planallScope" > -->
          <h4>{{planallScope.planall[0]}}</h4>
          <h4>{{planallScope.planall[1]}}</h4>
          <h4>{{planallScope.planall[2]}}</h4>
        </template>
      </cpn>
    </div>
    <template id="template_div">
      <div>
        <slot v-bind:planall="plan" name="slotName">
          <ul>
            <li v-for="item in plan"> {{ item }}</li>
          </ul>
        </slot>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.7/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
      const templateDivText = {
        template: '#template_div',
        data() {
          return {
            plan:  ['C#', 'Java', 'JavaScript']
          }
        },
      } 
    const app_new = new Vue({
      el: '#div_new',
      components: {
        'cpn': templateDivText,
      },
    })
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The running result is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAEev.png)

When I use v-slot, the code is as follows:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>17-Learning of Scoped Slots and Named Slots</title>
    <style>
      .h1Class{
        color:red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div_new">
      <h1 class="h1Class">first set</h1>
      <cpn></cpn>
      <h1 class="h1Class">second set</h1>
      <cpn>
        <!-- first method -->
        <!-- <template  slot="slotName" slot-scope="planallScope"> -->
        <!-- second method after Vue2.6 -->
        <template v-slot:slotName="planallScope" >
          <h4>{{planallScope.planall[0]}}</h4>
          <h4>{{planallScope.planall[1]}}</h4>
          <h4>{{planallScope.planall[2]}}</h4>
        </template>
      </cpn>
    </div>
    <template id="template_div">
      <div>
        <slot v-bind:planall="plan" name="slotName">
          <ul>
            <li v-for="item in plan"> {{ item }}</li>
          </ul>
        </slot>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.7/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
      const templateDivText = {
        template: '#template_div',
        data() {
          return {
            plan:  ['C#', 'Java', 'JavaScript']
          }
        },
      } 
    const app_new = new Vue({
      el: '#div_new',
      components: {
        'cpn': templateDivText,
      },
    })
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The running result is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWB7N.png)

So in Vue2.7, v-slot is not available, how to solve the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "is not available"? it is since 2.6.0

Comment: According to the official documents, vue2.6 and later versions support v-slot syntax, but when I use v-slot, I don't get the expected results, that means the results of the second image and the first image are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, except one little detail: you can't use camelCase for slot names.
To be fair, I don't precisely know why, it has to do with template compilation and with the fact the slot names get parsed as element attributes in `<template v-slot:slot-name"scope">`. Vue's styling guideline [*does* strongly advise](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/?redirect=true#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended) on using kebab-case for attributes, directives and the likes, when used in templates or JSX.
However, `name="slotName"` + `<template #slot-name="scope">` doesn't seem to work for slots.

In short, `name="slotName"` (+ `<template #slotName="scope"`) does not work, but `name="slot-name"` (+ `<template #slot-name="scope"`) does.

See it working, in Vue `2.7.7`:

```js
const templateDivText = Vue.defineComponent({
  template: '#template_div',
  data() {
    return {
      plan: ['C#', 'Java', 'JavaScript']
    }
  },
})
const app_new = new Vue({
  el: '#div_new',
  components: {
    'cpn': templateDivText,
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.7/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_new">
  <cpn>
    <template #slot-name="{planall}">
       <h4>{{planall[0]}}</h4>
       <h4>{{planall[1]}}</h4>
       <h4>{{planall[2]}}</h4>
     </template>
  </cpn>
</div>

<template id="template_div">
  <div>
     <slot name="slot-name" :planall="plan">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="item in plan"> {{ item }}</li>
        </ul>
      </slot>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Notes:

- `:planAll=""` is shorthand for `v-bind:planAll=""`
- `<template #slot-name="">` is shorthand for `<template v-slot:slot-name="">`
- when you only have one slot, you can remove the slot name altogether (it defaults to `name="default"`)

Comment: The restriction on attribute case exists because of such scenarios that are addressed by this guideline. The cause is known, DOM is case-insensitive, and so are templates that are retrieved from DOM. This won't happen if component template wasn't defined in DOM, e.g. as `template` string or SFC <template> block.